# Android Webview intercept IMG tag resource request and add headers

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview which renders HTML as a property of JSON response which I receive from an API. The HTML can have `<img src="">` tags. The server serving these images require several headers to be passed (way complicated than this but just simplifying stuff for the sake of question).

Is there any way I can intercept `<img src>` resource requests and add required headers in to request payload and pass it further?

I tried following overrides

- shouldInterceptRequest
- onLoadResource

but both are failing to catch the request for image resource.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any sample html which we can refer to understand problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it personally but can you try overiding shouldOverrideUrlLoading